# Limit of expected value of supremum and infimum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(\Theta,d)$ be a metric space, $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\Theta\times \mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$. Define $X$ as a random variable in $\mathcal{X}$. Suppose that the mapping $\theta\mapsto E[f(\theta,X)]$ is continuous.

For a fixed $\theta\in\Theta$ define the subsets $B_1(\theta),B_2(\theta),...$ as $B_j(\theta)=\{\theta':d(\theta,\theta')< 1/j\}$. Therefore, $B_1(\theta)\supset B_2(\theta)\supset\cdots $ and $B_j(\theta)\downarrow\{\theta\}$ as $j\to\infty$.

Is it true that 
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty}E\left[\sup_{\theta'\in B_j(\theta)}f(\theta',X) - \inf_{\theta'\in B_j(\theta)}f(\theta',X)\right] =  E[f(\theta,X)]-E[f(\theta,X)]=0\quad ?
$$
My approach was by defining $\theta_j^U$ and $\theta_j^L$ such that 
$$
f(\theta_j^U,X) = \sup_{\theta'\in B_j(\theta)}f(\theta',X),\quad f(\theta_j^L,X) = \inf_{\theta'\in B_j(\theta)}f(\theta',X).
$$
So by continuity, we have 
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty}E\left[\sup_{\theta'\in B_j(\theta)}f(\theta',X)\right]=\lim_{j\to\infty}E[f(\theta_j^U,X)]=E[f(\lim_{j\to\infty}\theta_j^U,X)]=E[f(\theta,X)].
$$
The weak arguments are that $\theta_j^U$ might not be well defined and that $\theta_j^U$ not necessarily converges to $\theta$ a.s.

Can anybody provide some insights? Is the affirmation true? If not, under what conditions is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true.  If we take $\Theta = [-1,1]$, $X = \pm 1$ with probability $\frac 12$, and define $$f(\theta, x) = \begin{cases} x & \theta \le 0 \\
-x & \theta > 0\end{cases}$$ then $\mathbb{E}[f(\theta,X)] = 0$ so in particular $\theta \mapsto \mathbb{E}[f(\theta,X)]$ is continuous.  However, if we fix $\theta = 0$ then $\sup_{\theta' \in B_j(0)} f(\theta',X) = 1$ and $\inf_{\theta' \in B_j(0)} f(\theta',X) = -1$ for every $j > 0$ so $$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\theta' \in B_j(0)} f(\theta',X) - \inf_{\theta' \in B_j(0)} f(\theta',X)\right] = 2.$$

I'm not sure exactly what the conditions you need are, but I would guess that at the very least you need $f(\theta,x)$ to be continuous in $\theta$.

Edit: If you have $\Theta$ is locally compact, $\theta \mapsto f(\theta,x)$ is continuous, and $\mathbb{E}[\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} |f(\theta,X)|] < \infty$, then the dominated convergence theorem gives

$$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\theta' \in B_j(\theta)} f(\theta',X) - \inf_{\theta' \in B_j(\theta)} f(\theta',X)\right] = \mathbb{E} \left[\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\left( \sup_{\theta' \in B_j(\theta)} f(\theta',X) \right)- \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\left( \inf_{\theta' \in B_j(\theta)} f(\theta',X)\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}[f(\theta,X) - f(\theta,X)] = 0$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't understand how did you use the continuity of $\theta\mapsto f(\theta,x)$. Is it sufficient that $\Theta$ is locally compact and $\theta\mapsto f(\theta,x)$ to conclude that $\lim_{j\to\infty}\sup_{\theta'\in B_j(\theta)}f(\theta',x)=f(\theta,x)$ ?

Comment: Yeah, the local compactness gives that the closure of $B_1(\theta)$ is compact (because it's a closed subset of a compact set) so $\theta \mapsto f(\theta,x)$ is uniformly continuous on the closure of $B_1(\theta)$.  This is slightly stronger than what we need because it actually means that $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{\theta_1,\theta_2 \in B_j(\theta)} |f(\theta_1,x)-f(\theta_2,x)| = 0$.